# Apple TV after awake from sleep mode SpriteKit Sounds do not play in SceneKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, tvos, apple-tv

I have a strange problem on tvOS! I am using SceneKit and SpriteKit! If my game goes in sleep mode > screen saver > then sleep mode and I wake it up all sounds with: SKAction.playSoundFileNamed aren’t playing anymore! SceneKit Sounds play perfect! If I send AppleTV to sleep mode with SiriRemote everything works perfect! Does anyone have the same issue? Any solutions?